# trouble with same font (Netbeans & Eclipse)

Tags: netbeans, fonts

![A problem with same font "Consolas"][1]

I got a problem on Netbeans about editor windows,
but on eclipse it is use another font method.

I 'ld like to use this font on Netbeans too because 
I like some feature in Netbeans IDE.

I try to solve with 
-J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -J-Dswing.aatext=true
but it change only menu bar.

I used on Windows 8 system.

Please help me, Thanks in advance.

This is my first time of post on here >> stackoverflow.com <<
I can't attach image please follow link of the pic.

http://s16.postimg.org/iimolt5wl/problem.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> Options -> Font and Color -> Font .. Select the font that you need.

Comment: in this method I know that's many font to select,
I need font Consolas because it easy to read and fix width font but it not support thai alphabet,
in eclipse that is show